# Encoding gif to base64 without writing to disk python

Tags: python, base64, animated-gif

I am able to encode a gif to base64 by saving the data first.

```
    imageio.mimsave(output_fn, [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in gif], fps=original_fps)

    with open(output_fn, "rb") as gif_file:
            detect_base64 = 'data:image/gif;base64,{}'.format(base64.b64encode(gif_file.read()).decode())
```

I need to find a way to encode the `gif` above in the form an array of images, with the corresponding `fps` into base64 without the need of saving it into `output_fn` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is to use a `BytesIO` as a replacement for an open file, i.e.

```
gif_file = io.BytesIO()

imageio.mimsave(gif_file, [img_as_ubyte(frame) for frame in gif], 'GIF', fps=original_fps)

detect_base64 = 'data:image/gif;base64,{}'.format(base64.b64encode(gif_file.getvalue()).decode())
```

Comment: imageio.misave cause an error

    ValueError: Could not find a format to write the specified file in mode 'I'

Comment: My guess is imageio infers format from the file name. If using a stream, you probably have to send in the format explicitly